# JPA / How to add a property in a ManyToMany relation

Tags: java, jpa, many-to-many, entity

I started to create 2 classes for my 2 entities :

- **User** : a User may belong to several Group
- **Group** : a Group may count several User (members)

The relation between these 2 entities should be **bidirectional**.

JPA will then create a new relation entity named User-Group. In this table/entity we will find the User PK and the Group PK together.

**My problem is :** 
each User in a Group should have a "role". Default role is "member", but a User can also be "leader".

The "role" property doesn't exist in any of my classes and should be associated with the couple "User PK / Group PK" of the User-Group relation table created by JPA.

How can I handle the "role" property as it is not a User property neither a Group property but a User-Group property ?
How to add this column in the User-Group table which is a JPA creation ?

Thanx for your help.

Comment: If it doesn't exist in your classes then it cant be persisted. So design your model correctly to INCLUDE the extra field (i.e have a class UserGroup) and THEN define its mappings (1-N User to UserGroup, 1-N Group to UserGroup). This is amply documented if you only search this site for other questions

Comment: Thanx a lot @Neil. You sure are right, I need to create this entity and its relationships with USER and GROUP.
I found some posts here but they didn't describe exactly what I needed.

First I thought it could be possible to use the relationship table created by JPA to add a single property named "Role", but I understand it's not possible to use such tables. A new entity has to be explicitely created.

Have a nice day and thanx a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to split the Many-to-Many in two One-To-Many relationships towards a new entity : you create a UserRoleInAGroup class containing the role field, a group and a user.

The 2 resulting One-To-Many relationships are :

- 1st :

  - Each User can be related to many UserRoleInAGroup
  - Each UserRoleInAGroup is related to a single User
- 2nd :

  - Each Group can be related to many UserRoleInAGroup
  - Each UserRoleInAGroup is related to a single Group

I hope it helps.